# In AWS security groups, what is the difference between setting a Custom TCP Rule on port 443 and setting an HTTPS rule (also on 443)?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, tcp, https

I'm creating a website and need to set up some boxes on AWS and create security groups for them. When creating a security group rule, I'm faced with the following options (abridged):

Type

---

1. Custom TCP Rule
2. ...
3. HTTPS
4. ...

So I'm wondering, what is the difference between setting a custom TCP rule on port 443 and setting a HTTPS rule (which is on port 443 by default)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference. HTTPS is a short cut which translates to TCP/443. Suppose your HTTPS server uses a non-standard port, then you can use the custom TCP port to specify the non standard port.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same thing. TCP is layer 4 and HTTPS is layer 7.
You can see this try connecting SSL site without https as show below.

http://www.google.com:443

You can´t connect because you try TCP connection on port 443 although 
using port 443 (SSL port).

If you change the http to https on site above you can connect it.

But if you select "SSL (secure TCP)" on port 443 you can connect it.

regards,